# Why don't the two programmes on Fibonacci sequence give similar output yet intuitively they seem similar

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
# program to generate the Fibonacci sequence 
a, b=0,1
while b<10:
     Print b
     a, b=b,a+b

# my intuitive substitute 
a=0
b=1
while b<10
     print b
     a=b
     b=a+b
```

The above snippet contains two programs, one from the Python docs, the other from intuitive me, I thought they would both produce similar results but the former outputs 1 1 2 3 5 8 and the latter 1 2 4 8. Could a good Samaritan kindly explain why?

Comment: Please post code here. Afterwards it's okay to link

Comment: If you assign `a=b` and **then after that** `b = a+b`, then you have simply doubled `b`. So you have made a doubling sequence. But if you update `a` and `b` together, you are adding the old value of `a` to `b`, so you get a Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
a, b=b,a+b
```

and these statements:

```
a=b
b=a+b
```

are not the same thing.  The former does all of the assignment before the variables have the new values.  The latter does one at a time.

So, for example, starting with `a = 0` and `b = 1`, step through the logic:

```
a, b=b,a+b
# a was set to 1
# and b was set to 0 + 1
```

conversely:

```
a=b
# a was set to 1
b=a+b
# b was set to 1 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, when you do `b = a+b`, you're using the modified `a` from the previous line. In Python's example, the vars are assigned simultaneously. For yours to work it should be:

```
a=0
b=1
while b<10:
     print b
     c=a
     a=b
     b=c+b
```

Comment: Why would you use an extra variable? Wouldn't `b = a + b` followed by `a = b - a` suffice? Also you're missing a colon on your `while` line.

Comment: Didn't catch the typo. Fixed it now.